# how do i move toggle buttons to a horizonal line?

Tags: html, css, button

I have toggle buttons that are in a line vertically. I would like to make them in a line horizontally. I know there is a way to do this but I forgot how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to arrange your element in 2D, use flex-box. If you want to arrange them in 3D, use Grid.

## Flex-box

```css
.btn-grp {
  diplay: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```